# How to get data from the past 12 months?

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation, python-datetime

I have a dataset that updates on a daily basis, and I am trying to create a bar chart that shows the number of sales for each sub-category within the past 12 months. This is what my dataset looks like:

```
Order Date Sub-Category     Customer Name     Sales
0    2016-11-08    Bookcases       Claire Gute  261.9600
1    2016-11-08       Chairs       Claire Gute  731.9400
2    2016-06-12       Labels   Darrin Van Huff   14.6200
3    2015-10-11       Tables    Sean O'Donnell  957.5775
4    2015-10-11      Storage    Sean O'Donnell   22.3680
```

My data goes all the way back to 2020 and to today's date. In the beginning I tried filtering but then I realized that the bars will not update because it's only going to give me data in the time frame that I set it to. Could someone please help me figure out how to get the number of sales within the past 12 months?

Comment: You want a the last 12 months of data for each Sub-Category depending on the last date available in that Sub-Category?  So, that Chairs might dates 2016-01-01 to 2017-01-01 because the last date is 2017-01-01.  Where Tables could be 2015-06-1 to 2016-06-01 because the last date in Tables is 2016-06-01.  Is this correct?

Comment: @ScottBoston I kind of messed up the dataset sorry about that. So, the latest date should be 2023-11-28 and the earliest should 2015-01-01. What I am trying to do is create a rolling window of the amount of sales within the past 12 months for each sub-cateogry

Comment: Try `df.groupby('Sub-Category)['Sales'].rolling(12, freq='M').mean()` this statement may need tweaking to work with your dataset.

Comment: @ScottBoston Thank you so much for your response this works, and I also wanted to know what if I was looking at the number of sales within the before the past 12 months. So the sum of sales before the 12 months cut off?